# Find My iPhone 3Gs

Tags: ios, iphone, find-my-iphone

Find My iPhone locates my phone when it's at home, but when it moves away from home it always shows the old location (Home) and never updates. My iPhone 5 using the same account works fine. How do I resolve this issue?

- iOS 6.2 or thereabout
- iCloud and Find My Phone on
- Wi-Fi on

Comment: When you take your iPhone 3G to a coffee shop and open maps, does it find the correct location? I'm guessing you don't have a data plan on the old phone and must use WiFi - could you confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

Is mobile data switched on on the phone. It is possible that it cannot update the lcoation data as it cant connect to the internet. You should check that mobile data is switched on and that your cell phone includes mobile data (and that you have sufficient allowance remaining).

Another thing to check would be to move the phone to another location where there is WiFi coverage and see if it updates the location data here.

If these steps fail to produce a satisfactory result then it may be a problem with the GPS on the phone. Open one of the maps apps and see if it displays your location accurately.